# How to Obtain The User Address By Knowing their Longitude and Latitude

Tags: android-location

I am using LocationManager in android application to obtain the user current coordinates. It works fine for me but the second step I want to display the formatted address to the user instead of displaying it in logn and lat format.
can you pleeease help me ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(Latitude, Longitude, 1);
```

Comment: thank you Dmitry,
but when I used it in emulator it tells me "service is not available".

Comment: You have to use the emulator with Google API. Create a new AVD and select the same platform you use but with Google API and run the app in this emulator. You can check if the device has the correct API with `Geocoder.isPresent()`.